# How do you implement your own src for the script

Tags: html

Ok, sorry for not wording the question correctly, and im not so good with words, but I was wondering, since you can get the scripts in HTML from the web, ex: `<script src='something'></script>` How do you make it to where you can put in your own src? Again, sorry for not being able to word this good, but if you understand could you please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the path to the script where is says src. ie: `<script src="js/app.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `src` attribute is just a URL.

Make the server return a resource (for that URL) with an `application/javascript` content-type and a JavaScript program as the content. This is usually achieved by uploading a text file, with a `.js` file extension, containing your JavaScript.